# Dependency loop while trying to install gcc on Fedora 17

Tags: fedora, yum, dependencies, gcc

I'm trying to `yum install gcc` but getting this message.

```
Error: Package: glibc-common-2.15-37.fc17.i686 (@anaconda-0)
       Requires: glibc = 2.15-37.fc17
       Removing: glibc-2.15-37.fc17.i686 (@anaconda-0)
           glibc = 2.15-37.fc17
       Updated By: glibc-2.15-57.fc17.i686 (updates)
           glibc = 2.15-57.fc17
       Removing: glibc-2.15-56.fc17.i686 (installed)
           glibc = 2.15-56.fc17
       Updated By: glibc-2.15-57.fc17.i686 (updates)
           glibc = 2.15-57.fc17
```

And, if it's helpful:

```
uname -a
Linux laptop 3.3.4-5.fc17.i686.PAE #1 SMP Mon May 7 17:37:39 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I'm not really sure how to resolve these issues.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is something's gone wrong with yum's internal cache. I'd start from a known good state:

First, connect the computer to the Internet.

Second, flush out yum's internal cache:

```
yum clean all
```

Third, apply outstanding updates:

```
yum upgrade
```

Now, try installing your program again:

```
yum install gcc
```

Comment: The `yum upgrade` failed unfortunately. I'll try removing a few packages which might be causing some problems. Thanks